# ASP.Net HttpCookie expiration set to two years

Tags: httpcookie

I create a cookie and set the Expires property to 24 hours, but in IE the expiration is set to two years.  In Firefox it is set correctly.  Why?

My code:

```
//Set a cookie to expire in 24 hours.
HttpCookie clickCookie = new HttpCookie(adId, adId);
clickCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(clickCookie);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be possible. Can you try again after erasing current cookies of IE?

Comment: I agree, it doesn't seem possible.  I tried your suggestion with no luck.  It again created a cookie that expires in 2011.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do:

```
clientCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
```

Answer (score 0):

triskelion, use Fiddler to sniff HTTP reqeuest and response pair for both IE nad Firefox and see if there's any difference.